# Can I use jQuery selectors on an HTML string that is not attached to the DOM?

Tags: jquery

So if I have a variable like

```
var ht = "<body><p>Paragraph Here</p></body>"
```

If it was attached to the DOM I could just do this to get the text

```
$('p').text();
```

But can I do the same kind of selection just on a variable that has not yet been attached to the dom?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The jQuery object will take HTML and make it in to a DOM structure for further query, you can pass it in directly to create the object, or use it as a context if you just wish to query it.

*Edit: For some reason it seems necessary to wrap it in a DIV, if not already within one in this example.  See the [jQuery object documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) on this method for further information.*

**See test framework for system at:** http://jsfiddle.net/hUMqU/

```
var ht = "<body><p>Paragraph Here</p></body>";
$('<div>' + ht + '</div>').find('p').text();
```

or as context:

```
var ht = "<body><p>Paragraph Here</p></body>";
$('p', '<div>' + ht + '</div>').text();
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I just copy and paste your code above into $(document).ready() neither returns a value.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still getting no value with both examples even when wrapped in a div

Comment: Which browser are you using, and what version of jQuery?  Remember that the routine creates actual DOM elements, the `<body>` tag may cause issues.  I've tested it in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I am using JQuery 1.4.4 from the Google CDN and Firefox 3.6.1.2

Comment: @TooFat Use Firebug or Google Chrome Developer Tools for testing and debugging such snippets interactively. Orbling's code contains a syntax error in the second line. Should be `'<div>'`, not `'<div'>`.

Answer (score 21):

There is no mystery. Selecting

```
$('p')
```

selects `p` elements of the document, the *implied context*.

But the `p` elements in:

```
var ht = "<body><p>Paragraph Here</p></body>";
```

are not attached to the document (DOM) so it's OK if they are not selected.

Fortunately the `$()` function has a second argument, the *context*, that has to be used here, like:

```
$('p', $(ht).context)
```

Comment: This needs more upboats

Answer (score 4):

Just wrap your HTML String into a jQuery object, and then you can run your jQuery selectors from there:

```
var htmlString = "<body><p>Paragraph Here</p></body>";
var elements = $(htmlString);

var p = elements.filter('p').text();
console.log(p);
//=> Paragraph Here
```

[Working demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/cmfuuo3n/).