# How is the solution for detecte DOM inserted by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do the automatic initialization when dom was inserted, I know there are several ways, but is that passable to do it like event listening on jQuery

In the past, we can do something like

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn_add">add</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#btn_add').on('click', function() {
    var html = $('<div class="new"></div>');

    $('.container').append(html);

});

$('.container').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.new', function() {
    $(this).html('new content');
});
```

But `DOMNodeInserted` was deprecated, We can do something like

```
$('#btn_add').on('click', function() {
    var html = $('<div class="new"></div>');

    $('.container').append(html).find('.new:last').trigger('created');

});

$('.container').on('created', '.new', function() {
    $(this).html('new content');
});
```

or

```
$('#btn_add').on('click', function() {
    var html = $('<div class="new"></div>');

    $('.container').append(html);

    doInit();
});

function doInit() {
    $('.container').find('.new:last').html('new content');
}
```

But it's not as beautiful as listen `DOMNodeInserted`, any better writing style?

Comment: There is the `mutationObserver` api: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event when element added to page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434685/event-when-element-added-to-page)

Comment: Also see [Can jQuery selectors be used with DOM mutation observers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596231/)

Comment: @JosuéZatarain I know this one, but it's only support IE11