# Replacing text being appended to a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I currently have this input box that takes the user's message and then appends it to a chat box like so:

```js
$('#messageBox').on('keydown', function (evt) {
    if( evt.keyCode == 13 ) {
      $("#chatBox").append(`<div class="UserMessage"><span class="Author" style="color: #fffff;"><span id="ID"></span>User : </span><span class="message">${$( this ).val()}</span></div>`)
    }
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="messageBox" type="text" placeholder="Your message here:">
<div id="chatBox" style="height: 350px; bottom: 50px;">
```

I would like to add a feature where it replaces any occurrences of a specific word with an image.

**Please note that:**
The only option I have is to do the replacement after the message has been sent out to the chatBox, since this is just some client-side code, so I won't be able to do the replacement before the message is sent out to the chatBox.

For example, I want to replace any occurrences of `:smileyface:` with an image link, while also keeping the text. For example; if the user enters `Hello:smileyface:` it would turn into `Hello(the image)`, if the user enters `Hello :smileyface:` it would turn into `Hello (the image)` and if the user enters just `:smileyface:` it would turn into `(the image)`.
So I tried something like this:

```
$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "#chatBox", function() { // detects when a message it appended to the chatBox
     $(".message").html(function (_, html) {
        return html.replace(/:smileyface:/g,"<img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrKSV.png' width ='35px'/>");
    });
});
```

However when trying this I got a never-ending error in console, which froze the window:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: well you modify the subtree each time so it is a loop.... Wouldn't it be easier to just do the replacement before you update the chat, not with this random listener?

Comment: There's a reason why `Be very careful with this event it is easy to cause an infinite loop if you decide to change the DOM inside the event handler` is mentioned on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified)

Comment: @epascarello Hi, the only option I have is to do the replacement after it has been detected in the #chatBox, since this is just some client-side code, so I won't be able to do the replacement before the message is sent out to the chatBox

Comment: So there is no way to alter the chat box code?

Comment: @epascarello No, unfortunately not. I have made an edit to the question to make things clearer.

Comment: well than you need to update the code only when it is has a replacement....

Comment: @epascarello I'm not sure how I would go about doing this.

Comment: Still not sure why you can not change $('#messageBox').on('keydown', function (evt) ....

Comment: I can suggest good tutorial link if you want :)

Comment: @epascarello Reason being I just wrote up that code snippet as an example to help illustrate my question. The code snippet is code I don't have access to. I am simply making a user script, that replaces words in the chatBox with images client-side.

Comment: In that case, you could try using the newer standard [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). You can see an example with jQuery here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596231/can-jquery-selectors-be-used-with-dom-mutation-observers.

Comment: @tudorpavel Thank you very much, feel free to add an answer so I can accept it and close off this question.

Comment: @newbie I'm glad I could help. I've edited my initial answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `'keydown'` code is not in your control, you could try using the newer standard [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect DOM changes.

You can see an example with jQuery here: [Can jQuery selectors be used with DOM mutation observers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596231/can-jquery-selectors-be-used-with-dom-mutation-observers)

Answer (score 0):

You are having this done on `DOMSubtreeModified`. So the first `:smileyface:` it comes across, it replaces with your image, but that fires another `DOMSubtreeModified`

I would instead, replace all of the :smileyface: occurrances in your keydown function

```
var message = $( this ).val();
message = message.replace(/:smileyface:/g,"<img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrKSV.png' width ='35px'/>");
$("#chatBox").append('<div class="UserMessage"><span class="Author" style="color: #fffff;"><span id="ID"></span>User : </span><span class="message">${message}</span></div>');
```

Comment: Please see the note I added to the question in the recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

since you mention this is just the client-side code, 
i suppose there **will** be some function/event to handle the new data when it is  retrieved.

you can then put the "replace code" in that event handler, instead of in a DOMSubtreeModified event (because, like mentioned previously, everytime you update, you will call the DOMSubtreeModified again and again, in an infinite loop)

```
function newMessageReceived(message){
    message = message.replace(/:smileyface:/g,"<img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrKSV.png' width ='35px'/>");
    $("#chatBox").append(`<div class="UserMessage"><span class="Author" style="color: #fffff;"><span id="ID"></span>User : </span><span class="message">${message}</span></div>`)
}
```