# Detect length div after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble detecting length and index of the appended div, I dug through a lot of things, and there's a solution with `MutationObservers` but somehow I'm continuously asking myself do I need it for this kind of problem,

However, let's get to the issue. I have a div populated dynamically structured like this,

```
<div class="array-placeholder">
   <div id="tagContainer" class="row tag">

     <!-- dynamic elements -->.....

   </div>
</div>
```

when I click to this button it appends another dynamic element, see the code below :

```
 $('body').off('click.addCollection').on('click.addCollection', function () {

 //list and new widgets are just containers and datalist inside the array-placeholder div  
 let newElem = $(list.attr('data-widget-tags')).html(newWidget);
    newElem.appendTo(list);

 })
```

I've tried this solution to get the length of the `array-placeholder` div but it doesn't seem to work, the function is never launched:

```
$('body').on('DOMSubtreeModified', '.array-placeholder', function (event) {
    console.log( $(".array-placeholder > div").length);
})
```

result

```
//nothing and when you click to the appended element via moveUpButton.closest(".tag")  you 0 as index
```

do I have to implement `MutationObserver` to solve this if yes, could you guide me through this, thanks

Comment: Why can't you just call a function after the `.appendTo(list);`?

Comment: I need the length as global variable to use it in other function

Comment: Why a global variable? There's almost always a better way than a global variable. And a `document.querySelectorAll("div.array-placeholder > div").length` isn't really that costly (especially not when compared with an active mutation observer!).

Comment: ```document.querySelectorAll("div.array-placeholder > div").length``` will always display the same value because when i append a div inside array-placeholder , it doesn't detect changes and even the appended element get 0 as index ...

Comment: Just call `.querySelectorAll()` when ever you need to know the number of elements. That's a really cheap operation. And if you're really only interested in the direct childrens of the list then you can even use `document.querySelector("div.array-placeholder").children.length` (you can even store a reference to `.children` and then just check its `.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all children using jquery's find('*') and then count their length;

`$(".array-placeholder").find('*').length;`

Or if you want only `div`s then do:

`$(".array-placeholder").find('div').length;`

Comment: This ```$(".array-placeholder").find('.tag').length``` this actually worked after i have done some changes

Answer (score 2):

[**`DOMSubtreeModified`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Events/DOMSubtreeModified)

> This event has been deprecated in favor of the [Mutation Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Yes you have to use [Mutation Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). To implement that you can refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59455864/how-can-i-get-to-know-while-a-class-changed-via-jquery/59455979#59455979)